# Opening Only Specific URLS on Safari instead of webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, safari

Im working on a web based application, it contains only one webView, the code below:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )) { 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]] ;

    }
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];
        // Set determinate mode
        [HUD show:YES];

        //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
        NSURL *url = [request URL];
       NSString *urls=   [url absoluteString];
        NSString *code = [urls substringFromIndex: [urls length] - 1];
        if ( [urls containsString:@".html"] && ![code isEqualToString:@"#"] ) {
          _webView.hidden= YES;
    }
```

this code will open all the web views on safari , but i only need to open specific URLs on safari
for example : 
 http://xxxx/residential/ this must be opened on safari, while all the other pages should be opened on webView inside the application.
Any help

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you want to open specific urls that should open in Safari instead of UIWebView. But there is not any conditions that fulfill your requirement.

First check your `[request url]` with your desired url. If both matched then open that url in `SFSafariViewController` instead of `openUrl` function. in `else` conditon you can load your `[request url]` which you don't want to open in Safari.